# Side menu with dynamic table cell will navigate page but with navigation controller coming as nil

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have create sidemenu using [this](http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/).

But the difference is only i have used dynamic `UITableViewCell` instead of static.

Now i face navigation issue while click on side menu item.

I have used navigation code like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    let propertyListing = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PropertyListing") as! PropertyListingController
    self.showViewController(propertyListing as UIViewController, sender: propertyListing )
}
```

It will navigate the page but navigation controller will be nil after that.

What can be the issue ? Any suggestion will be most appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a "show", you need to push the new view controller.

```
self.navigationController.pushViewController(propertyListing, animated: true)
```